# Conditions on an sql query to return specific records

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I'm creating an sql query where i have 3 fields --> NUMBER,COMPANY_NAME,END_DATE.
What i'm trying to do is give the user the option to whether input or not input NUMBER and COMPANY...But END_DATE must be mandatory. However when i leave both NUMBER and COMPANY empty, and only input END_DATE, i don't receive any record. Any help?

```
where L.NUMBER = $P{LEASE_NUMBER}
OR L.COMPANY_NAME = $P{COMPANY_NAME}
AND (L.END_DATE BETWEEN $P{DateFrom} AND $P{DateTo}
OR $X{EQUAL, L.END_DATE, dateRange})
```

Comment: Well for a start there is no SELECT clause :/ If you want an accurate answer you should include all the information

Comment: @Anton like the select clause is going to affect the query...

Comment: I find that the SELECT clause tends to be rather important when it comes to writing a query

Comment: maybe or maybe not. It doesnt effect the question in theory but then it may still actually be the reason the query returns nothing. It would not be the first time this was the case. You assume too much. Either way, information should always be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is closer to the logic you are looking for:

```
where (L.NUMBER = $P{LEASE_NUMBER} OR $P{LEASE_NUMBER} IS NULL) and
      (L.COMPANY_NAME = $P{COMPANY_NAME} OR $P{COMPANY_NAME} IS NULL) and
      (L.END_DATE BETWEEN $P{DateFrom} AND $P{DateTo} OR
       $X{EQUAL, L.END_DATE, dateRange}
      )
```

I'm not sure about the expression on time.  Your question has not explanation of `DateFrom`.

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
WHERE (L.NUMBER       = $P{LEASE_NUMBER} OR $P{LEASE_NUMBER} = '')
  AND (L.COMPANY_NAME = $P{COMPANY_NAME} OR $P{COMPANY_NAME} = '')
  AND L.END_DATE >= $P{DateFrom} AND L.END_DATE <= $P{DateTo}
```